# How to recognize names from a text using php

Tags: php, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I want to extract name(firstnames and lastnames) from a text using php.
Example:
From text below I want to extract names(in this case Aline Wright and Jesse Wright)

> Aline Wright is a cancer survivor,
>   amputee and a newlywed.  Wednesday
>   night she began to show signs she was
>   having a stroke.
>
> "I started feeling some left arm
>   numbness and a facial droop," said
>   Aline.
>
> "It appeared to me that I was probably
>   having a stroke."
>
> That's when her husband of four days,
>   Jesse Wright, put her in the car and
>   rushed her to the Erlanger Medical
>   Center. Wright knows an emergency. He
>   is a nurse technician at Erlanger.

Comment: And what about names of people with initials, "I. M. Robot" or "I M Robot"?

Answer (score 13):

If you want to do **[named entity recognition (NER)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_entity_recognition)** using PHP, you'll need to either call out to **an external NER package** or make use of an online **natural language processing API**.

**APIs**

NLP API are listed below. Complexity Intelligence and Alchemy API will probably be moderately easier to use for beginners than OpenCalais.

- [Complexity Intelligence](http://www.complexityintelligence.com) - see the PHP named entity tagging sample code [here](http://www.complexityintelligence.com/en/knowledgebase/api/nlp_ner_v1/snippet_php).
- [Alchemy API](http://www.alchemyapi.com/) - download their PHP SDK [here](http://www.alchemyapi.com/tools/).
- [OpenCalais](http://www.opencalais.com) - see the PHP sample code [here](http://www.opencalais.com/applications/opencalais-and-php-code).
- [No Code API](https://nocodeapi.net) - by using their api-calls provide text which u need to process. 10K free requests is quite enough for checking any hypothesis.

**NER Packages**

A few software packages you can use for NER are:

- [Stanford CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml) (Java)
- [LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/) (Java)
- [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) (Python)
- [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/) (Java)
- [YamCha](http://chasen.org/~taku/software/yamcha/#download) (C++)

Of these, Stanford CoreNLP is probably a good place to start. Similar to many NLP APIs, it provides a complete processing pipeline for common tasks such as NER.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a named entity recognizer. There are many of these up on **CPAN** where there is an active linguistics community.

Then, in **PHP**, do something like:

```
$result = \`perl named_entity_recogniser.pl "myText"\`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this PHP extension but be prepared to compile from source. 
https://github.com/rjjakes/MITIE-PHP

Comment: It's fine to put the extension here, indeed it's helpful. But you should elaborate a bit and tell as in three or four lines how you solve the problem. Thank you