# How to spot the specific string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, extract

My code is

```
$data = "met with a good salesperson in sunway carnival. her name is Katie Hopkins, manager of Marketing & Sales. Her mobile phone is 0165531477.
And then, met with Katie Holmes, her mobile phone is 0123456777.";

echo preg_match('\h*(\d+)',$data);
```

I want to retrieve the particular information from the string, `$data` and then assign the people name into array `$name[]` and also their mobile phones into array `$mobile[]`. Below is the example, but I don't know how to do php coding to get the people name and their mobile phone numbers into the particular array.

```
$name[0] = 'Kean Teck';
$mobile[0] = '0165531477';

$name[1] = 'Katie Hopkins';
$mobile[1] = '0123456777';
```

Comment: You can do this with regular expression.

Comment: So text proceeding `mobile phone is` and `her/his name is`?

Comment: Chris85: yes, you are right.

Comment: I know regular expression, but I don't know to to use regular expression to get the result.

Comment: In PHP specifically or how? Can you show what you are having issues with? I'd imagine a regex such as `mobile phone is\h*(\d+)` and `(?:her|his) name is\h*(.+?),` would suffice.

Comment: it's not working with error: WARNING preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'n' on line number 5

Comment: Update with your code.

Comment: however, is it preg-match can find just one string? I need to spot more than two strings.

Comment: Function is `preg_match_all`.

Comment: So your regex lacks delimiters and it will never match the user's name.

Comment: Fiddle around with this, https://eval.in/441955..

Comment: if you want to filter out names in a generic text, then the most efficient way is to jump into nlp. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4308312/2083738

Comment: Thanks Chris. You solved my problem.

Comment: To test it you could also use http://www.phpliveregex.com/