# Regex to find names in a string using PHP

Tags: php

I would like to find all the names in a string using regex. I do not mind if I catch words or groups of words that are not names.

I'm new to regex so would be grateful if someone could help.

```
$str = 'It was first suggested by Tom Boyd then afterwords by William H John Smith on Monday. But on Wednesday Simon Nixon did not agree stating that he and Terry Wallace, Joan C and K. Harris categorically disagreed with Tom Boyd and William H John Smith.';
preg_match_all("/[A-Z][a-z']+(?: [A-Z][a-z]+)*/",$str,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

That gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => It
            [1] => Tom Boyd
            [2] => William
            [3] => John Smith
            [4] => Monday
            [5] => But
            [6] => Wednesday Simon Nixon
            [7] => Terry Wallace
            [8] => Joan
            [9] => Harris
            [10] => Tom Boyd
            [11] => William
            [12] => John Smith
        )

)
```

Errors are William H John Smith, Wednesday Simon Nixon, Joan C and K. Harris.

Comment: Hi Modboy!  Given your description here - what is the problem with the output you're getting?  It is not trivial to recognize names in a string, as you can imagine.. But if all you want to do is pull out strings of one or more capitalized words that can be done!

Comment: You are absolutely right Rebecca. This is why I don't mind if I catch words or groups that are not names. And that's exactly what I need. Please note errors. Pulling "It" or "But" is not an error. I need help correcting my regex to pull the other four names. I completely accept that I may also pull words that are not names. So long as I get all the names in full then my question is answered.

Comment: Possible duplication with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304938/how-to-recognize-names-from-a-text-using-php

Comment: No that post had external api calls making the answer overly complicated. If anyone was trying to find names they would have their own array of eg client names. You see I'm not bothered if I get words or groups which are not names so long as it also outputs all names and I'm able to find all client names in the array. All that is required here is regex. I just need someone to help with regex as I'm completely new to it.